# Visual Studio 2008 SFTP?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ftp

So... we're into the year 2010 now, has anyone found a nice FTP plugin for Visual Studio yet? Something that looks like this perhaps (from EditPlus):

[image]

I just want to be able to (double-)click a file to open it, and then hit Ctrl+S to save it back to the site.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) with the [ftp plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/FTP_synchronize/) to do exactly this. Also loads faster than VS. Of course, it's not VS.

Comment: Yeahhh... but it's *really* ugly :\ I much prefer EditPlus if I'm going to use a lightweight editor.

Comment: the FTP plugin has an incredibly kludgey GUI, the menubar is littered with garbage, and the Python syntax highlighting... doesn't even recognize triple quoted strings.

Answer (score 1):

Not a VS2008 plugin, but I've found that mounting the drive and working like normal is really nice when working on a project. Software to do this is for example: [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/windows)

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying ExpanDrive but I can't seem to get a Solution Explorer in VS that way, *and* it kills the responsiveness of Visual Studio when browsing or uploading.