# Visual Studio plugins for ftp?

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, ftp

Any good FTP Plugins out there for VS 2005/2008?

Comment: What do you want to use it for?  The publish feature for sites already supports FTP, are you after something else?

Comment: VS publish feature seems to be an "all-or-nothing" solution. If I make a change to only one file I don't want to have to wait for VS to upload all 200+ files in my project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2008 SFTP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429512/visual-studio-2008-sftp)